# How to parse and display JSON Data in TVML file

Tags: javascript, swift, swift3, apple-tv, tvml

My current project is reachable here: [GitHub](https://github.com/DanylS/AppleTV)

I'm trying to retrieve data from product.json file into my productsTemplate.tvml (FunTV/templates).

How to use JS variable into .TVML file ? I'm looking to iterate and display all the product name from product.json.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please a minimal complete verifiable example. Note that just posting a link to a github project isn't really acceptable. You'll only need to make a few more commits for the code you refer to to be buried in the history.

Comment: I'm just asking if some of you have ever met my problem. I also did some search about this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/145100/tvos-tutorial-using-tvml-templates, they use mustache.js

Answer (score 0):

So you have your json file like this :

```
[
{"url": "your_image_url1", "title": "Your Title1"},
{"url": "your_image_url2", "title": "Your Title2"} ]
```

In your javascript file, you make a function called parseJson :

```
function parseJson(information) {
//push a loadingdocument ( loadingTemplate() ) onto the navigationstack
var loadingDocument = loadingTemplate();
navigationDocument.pushDocument(loadingDocument);
var result = JSON.parse(information);
//make an empty string that fills with the image information in the loop
var movies ="";
//loop until you fill all your json files
for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
   movies += '<lockup><img src="' + baseURL + result[i].url + '" />
<title>' + result[i].title + '</title></lockup>';
}
// make a costum template with your images string movies.
var template = '<document><stackTemplate><banner><title>JSON 
Shelf</title></banner><collectionList><shelf><section>' + movies + 
'</section></shelf></collectionList></stackTemplate></document>';
var templateParser = new DOMParser();
var parsedTemplate = templateParser.parseFromString(template, 
"application/xml");
//replace the loadingdocument with your parsedtemplate. done.
navigationDocument.replaceDocument(parsedTemplate, loadingDocument);
}
```